# Troubleshooting Power Issue in Bernina 290 Foot Pedal

Tags: resistors, hardware, troubleshooting

I have a Bernina 290 foot pedal for a sewing machine that started to only work at full throttle or nothing. I opened it up and found the way that the circuit regulates speed is with what I believe is a sort of variable resistor using a carbon strip to vary resistance depending on how far the pedal is pushed down.

When the pedal is pressed the white piece with two connected carbon rods makes contact with both sides of the strip on the circuit board completing the circuit. Depending on where it is on the strip (either high up or low down) the machine will run slow or fast.

Why does it only work on the bottom part of the strip? It does not touch the metal rivets at the bottom so I know that the carbon strip works there but it will not work at the top.

[image: strip]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you get a more in-focus version of the second picture? I think I see a bad solder joint, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: The element is probably broken or dirty or worn to the point where it only runs in an area that achieves low impedance completion of the circuit.  Sewing machines (at least non-big-box-store models) still slightly have a repair tradition, so parts (or at least a replacement foot pedal) may be available.  Newer designs may be electronic rather than resistive.

Comment: @duskwuff The picture with the white plastic piece with the two carbon rods? There is no solder joint there...behind the carbon rods are two springs which touch a metal plate so that they are electrically connected together.

Comment: Sorry, meant the third picture.

Comment: @duskwuff There you go...does look a little strange...I can see the metal piece through the solder.

Comment: Turns out it was a 0.01uf capacitor. The case was cracked so I bought one from Mouser electronics...soldered it on and what do you know...it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a 0.01uf capacitor on the board that was the culprit. The case was cracked so I bought one from Mouser electronics...soldered it and it worked!

Comment: how did you know which capacitor to buy at Mouser? Can you tell me which one you ordered? I need to do the same repair to my Bernina 290 pedal. Thanks much.

Comment: @lhava It has been awhile but I think it was because it was “puffed” that I knew it needed replacement. I don’t know much about electronics but I know if the top is sort of domed instead of flat it needs to be replaced. Once you find busted capacitors just read the side and it will tell you the uf and voltage ratings. Then just search that on mouser. If you show me a pic of the top I might could spot bad capacitors and find it on Mouser for you.